# How to get desired table with recursive Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have these tow tables. The items in column 2 of table 1 may also be related to other items and their relations are in table 2.

```
 t1  Code_A|Code_B   t2   Code_B|Code_C
     ------+------        ------+------
     788   |   501        501   |   503
     788   |   510        503   |   507
     ...   |   ...        501   |   504
```

How can I get table 1 as this result using recursive query in sql server.

```
result  Code_A|Code_B  
        ------+------       
        788   |   501      
        788   |   503        
        788   |   507
        788   |   504
```

**Edited**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with  [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)  :

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Code_A INT, Code_B INT)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (Code_B INT, Code_C INT)


INSERT @t1 VALUES (788, 501), (788, 510)
INSERT @t2 VALUES (501, 503), (503, 507)


;WITH cte(code_A, code_B)
AS (
    SELECT t1.code_A, t1.code_B
    FROM @t1 t1
    LEFT JOIN @t2 t2 ON t2.Code_B = t1.Code_B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.code_A, t2.code_C
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN @t2 t2 ON t2.Code_B = c.code_B
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cte
```

result:

```
code_A      code_B
----------- -----------
788         510
788         501
788         503
788         507
```

Comment: Works like a charm with the given desired output. But since he wrote *may be related*, it's possible that he also wants `788, 510` (with the assumption that 510 is not present in t2) but just didn't include it to keep the sample short. Suggest you add a separate case for this output, in case it's what the OP wants.

Comment: @stephen thanks for your answer but as I see now I want something a little different from what I asked and I edited my question. In table 2 some Codes in column Code_B my be repeated so with the above Code some same rows in result table will be repeated multiple times. I think by adding `Distinct` to last row the problem will be solved.

Comment: @user1429080 Yes. I want `788, 510` too And to see it I can replace `inner join` with `left join` in the first part of recursive query.